# Is there a way to fold custom annotations?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea

For example, With `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")`, the annotation becomes `/SuppressWarnings/`

I'd like to apply the same to other annotations, such as `BindView(R.id.blabla)`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: @mallaudin Same reason I like it for SuppressWarnings and others like it... to reduce clutter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems not, there is no way to do that.

You can fold *all* annotations by enabling a checkbox in Settings > Editor > Code Folding > Annotations.

You can also configure [`custom folding regions`](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/custom-code-folding-regions-in-intellij-idea-111/) (add meta comments for a file) - that will make folding buttons appear on the left. If you want these regions to fold automatically, you'll have to enable the checkbox in the same setting (Settings > Editor > Code Folding > Custom folding regions).

P.S. Why, though

Comment: @MSPrimaVista glad I helped! Yout can always [open a feature request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA) they actually respond quite fast. P.S. should probably accept the answer